# selenium cucumber, test if disabled elements are disabled

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I have a table that has a column , that td should be enabled or disabled :

```
 <tr><td>
<i aria-hidden="true" title="Already Assigned" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out icon-spacing assigned"></i>
</tr></td>
....

<tr><td>
<i aria-hidden="true" title="Assign to Self" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out icon-spacing"></i>
<tr><td>
```

I want to test if all i having the class assigned are really disabled, I tried only once I don't know how to collect all of them than do the test (assert or expect), with cucumber I did :

```
Then element having class "assigned" should be disabled
```

But It did not work, I got :

```
Then element having class "assigned" should be disabled
selenium-cucumber-3.1.5/lib/selenium-cucumber/assertion_steps.rb:31
expected false
     got true
 (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

Please your help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: While trimming the `HTML` you have chopped off the `required` tags/details from the `HTML`. Currently the `HTML` is not in valid state to debug. Update the exact `Manual Step` which you are trying to `Automate`.

Comment: @Majid, asserting `enabled or disabled` implies asserting whether a user can or can not perform an action. So try to perform the action and evaluate whether there's an exception or not. But be aware that checking `whether an element having class "assigned" should be disabled` is not a valid e2e test since the record may be assigned with the wrong class or may be missing the class.

Comment: Here is the whole html table :  https://justpaste.it/1g78f

Comment: @Florent B, the test I want to do is : testing if you can not reassign again, any thought will be helpful.

Comment: While the link to the entirety of the HTML might be useful now, it will likely disappear in the future leaving this question without a good part of the info needed to understand it. It's best to add the relevant portion of the HTML to the question, properly formatted. Also, avoid posting relevant info in comments. Instead add them to the question and then add a comment stating that you've added info.

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` attribute is really only relevant for `INPUT` tags. You could do a couple things...

1. Verify that the `assigned` class is present/missing on the element. This assumes that the `assigned` class is the one and only control of if the link is disabled. You'll have to decide if that is a safe bet or not. Another variation here that I just noticed is you can see that the title is "Already Assigned"... that may be another or alternative way to verify.
2. Click the link again and verify that the site doesn't behave like the link is enabled. I don't know what that behavior might be... a dialog opening, part of the page changing, etc. If the change doesn't happen, you can safely assume that the button is disabled. I think this is probably the safer and more reliable of the two options.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm if the *td* is *enabled* or *disabled* you can redefine the test (assert or expect) with cucumber as follows :

```
Then element having title "Already Assigned" should contain the class "disabled"
```